# No puedo insertar objeto en una Class en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, javascript-objeto

Tengo un problema a la hora de insertar un nuevo objeto (con todos su

```javascript
function crearClaseViajero() {
      class Viajero {
        constructor(nombre, edad, paises, compañeros) {
          // El constructor de la clase Viajero recibe nombre (string), edad (integer), paises (array de strings), compañeros (array de objetos)
          // Inicializar las propiedades del viajero con los valores recibidos como argumento

          // Tu código aca:
          this.nombre=nombre;
          this.edad=edad;
          this.paises=paises;
          this.compañeros=compañeros;
    }

        addCompañero(nombre, nacionalidad, edad) {
          // El método 'addCompañero' recibe un string 'nombre', un string 'nacionalidad' y un entero 'edad' y
          // debe agregar un objeto:
          // { nombre: nombre, nacionalidad: nacionalidad, edad: edad} al arreglo de compañeros del viajero.
          // No debe retornar nada.

          **var nuevoViajero = new Viajero ({nombre: nombre, nacionalidad: nacionalidad, edad: edad});**
```

Me tira el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que puede llegar a ser? Gracias

Comment: `this.compañeros=compañeros` tiene que ser una lista, pero no lo vemos ya que no dejaste el código, también tienes que tener un sistema de identificar a quien le agregas el compañero, pero en el enunciado no pone nada. Creo que aquí falta información

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so], haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Por favor, pon un título más descriptivo, así logras atraer más atención a la pregunta, y muestra el mensaje de error _como texto_, para mejor legibilidad. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con el siguiente codigo a mi me ejecuto correctamente la funcion definiendo el metodo addCompañero de esta manera.

```
addCompañero(nombre, nacionalidad, edad) {
          // El método 'addCompañero' recibe un string 'nombre', un string 'nacionalidad' y un entero 'edad' y
          // debe agregar un objeto:
          // { nombre: nombre, nacionalidad: nacionalidad, edad: edad} al arreglo de compañeros del viajero.
          // No debe retornar nada.
this.compañeros.push({nombre, edad});
```

OJO! Faltaba codigo para indicarte el porque del error pero como me paso lo mismo pude deducir que tambien podia estar erroneo el getCompañeros()

Y el codigo completo seria

```
class Viajero {
    constructor(nombre, paises, compañeros) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.paises = paises;
        this.compañeros = compañeros;
    }

    getPaises() {
        
        return this.paises;
    }

    getCompañeros() {
        return this.compañeros.map(compañeros => compañeros.nombre);
    }

    addPais(pais) {
        this.paises.push(pais);
    }

    addCompañero(nombre, edad) {
        this.compañeros.push({nombre, edad});
       
    }
}
```

Ojala te ayude, saludos.

Comment: Revisar (https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3195/por-qu%c3%a9-me-quitaron-400-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n/3196#3196) y [answer].